# encoding issue with apostrophe and wkhtmltoimage

Tags: php, html, encoding

I have an escaped apostrophe:

```
&#39;
```

that turns into this:

```
тАЩ
```

when I try to convert it to image using wkhtmltoimage library.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

I know it's encoding, but not sure what to replace it with.

Regular apostrophe and backquote are also displayed wierd.

And I need it for words like "don't".

PHP is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try `--encoding=utf8` while executing the command.